# Converting to correct SQL date stamp results to cast error

Tags: jasper-reports

My goal is to select all orders from today.

Database format: 
system_entry_date = 05-30-2016 12:47:00.0096

```
$P{today}
java.sql.Date
Is for prompting: Yes
Expression: new java.sql.Date(new java.util.Date().getTime())

$P{sqltoday}
java.sql.Date
Is for prompting: No
Expression: new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm").format($P{today})
```

SQL query: WHERE system_entry_date = $P{sqltoday}

Error: String cannot be cast to java.util.Date

The prompting is 30-6-17 and the SQL date format is 06-30-2017. This the reason that I have used the simpledateformat.

I don't see what's going wrong. Do anyone see the problem? Thanks for any help/tips.

Comment: `new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm").format($P{today})` - with this expression you are casting Date to String. In case using String parameter you need to use `$P!{sqltoday}` and convertation this string to Date with rules of yours DB

Comment: Thanks Alex. How can I switch to another format with keeping the Date?
It seems that it's almost impossible to convert string to Date.

Comment: In most cases you can just pass the Date parameter. You have wrong expression (the parameter declared as Date, but expression get String). If you need to pass date as String you should use query expression like this: `table.some_date_attribute > to_date('$P!{dateAsString}', 'YYYY/MM/DD'))` (PostgreSQL sample)

Comment: The issue is that java.util.Date().getTime() gives another format then the date format which is used in the DB.

The to_date function which convert the string to a date works perfect! Thanks again for your great help!